# GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit packagekit.service not found

Tags: 20.04

I use ubunto 20.04 and when I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit packagekit.service not found.
```

When I run:

```
sudo reboot
```

I get:

```
Failed to open initctl fifo: No such device or address
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Please don't use `sudo reboot -f` because you will not be able to connect again through the terminal.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try starting service
`sudo systemctl start packagekit.service`
if it wont help try finding is service still on the system

```
dpkg -l | grep packagekit
```

if not install it again, if it is broken try running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a --force
```

Comment: I tried to start it but it said service not found

Answer (score 0):

In that case try first ruining

```
sudo apt-get -y purge packagekit
```

it will remove any configuration files left by service then simply install it again with
`sudo aptitude -y install packagekit`